# How to fix HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:56981/gshxmXx3bLA=/

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, firebase-authentication, http-headers

I have build a flutter app and when i try to run, the app stops and shows the device lost the connection. And its showing error : HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:56981/gshxmXx3bLA=/ .I have used firebase for google sign.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the issue report for this specific problem at flutter's github @ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32696

If your problem remains after trying fixes suggested there, you'll need to provide an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can find the best answer for you, a lack of code ultimately does not lead to a good answer and your learning, rather, someone providing the answer for you.